# Topdiv with 100% width but body width 600px

Tags: css, html, width

I'm trying to create a div (topbar) (width = 100%;). Below that I want my maincontent in a div with my maincontent. This needs to be 600px in width and centeret in the screen.

Normally I would set body width = 600px and margin: auto, but then my topbar is shortened.

Whats the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to touch the width of the body element

```
#topbar {
    width:100%;
    height: 150px; // Whatever height you want
 }

 #mainContent {
   width: 600px;
   margin: 0 auto; // Center on the screen
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. This one was the solution I was looking for. Great help! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want `#topbar` to extend 100% of the width of the page which it is not currently doing if the browser window is less than 600px... because `#maincontent` pushes the page out past 600px?

I believe you will need to have a `body { min-width:600px; }` to force `topbar` to 600px if the page is less than 600px wide.

Here's a fiddle of a potential solution: http://jsfiddle.net/z2dEK/1/

And here's the CSS:

```
body {
    background:#ccc;
    min-width:600px;
}
#topbar {
    background:#000;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
}
#maincontent {
    background:#fff;
    margin:auto;
    width:600px;
    height:100px;
}
```